# How can i transfer repeated call to same queue member in asterisk

Tags: queue, asterisk

I am using queue and i want to map one caller to one executive.As if i call in the queue and you receive my call then next time if i call in the queue so call will automatically forwarded to you not other members of queue. Is there any option in queue configuration for do that...?

Comment: I think you can manage a database for that and when the repeated call comes check the  db and forward it to corresponding member.

Comment: Can you Please suggest any dialplan for it..?

Answer (score 1):

You need do something like this

```
exten => _X.,1,Set(ext=${ODBC_check_info(${CALLERID(num)})})
exten => _X.,2,GotoIF($[ "${ext}" != "" ]?from-internal,${ext},1); if match, call ext
exten => _X.,3,Goto(from-psnt,${EXTEN},1); if nto match,go default route
```

Sure you also need define odbc function check_info and setup odbc. 
Also need write some info who answered to some table(using queue_log or dial cmd on-answer-macro)

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+func_odbc